# Cufon causing gap in drop down menu

Tags: css, cufon

I'm stuck on a problem with the drop down menu on this site http://www.leithonthefringe.com/ (hover over performer information to see problem).

Basically a large gap appears between the main menu and the first item in the drop down, it affects FF/IE/Chrome.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated!

CSS is as follows:

```
#menu-main-nav {    margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
#menu-main-nav li { float: left; list-style: none; height: 40px; font-size: 20px; }
#menu-main-nav li a { display: block; background: #333333; padding: 12px 24px 8px 24px; text-decoration: none; border-right: 1px solid #444444; color: #EAFFED; white-space: nowrap; }
#menu-main-nav li a:hover { background: #222222; }
#menu-main-nav li ul {  margin: 0px; padding: 0px; height: 40px; position: absolute; visibility: hidden; border-top: 1px solid white; z-index: +1 }
#menu-main-nav li ul li { float: none; display: inline; }
#menu-main-nav li ul li a { width: auto; background: #750000; color: #FFFFFF; border-right: none;  }
#menu-main-nav li ul li a:hover { background: #8d0101; }
```

//Update

The problem seems to be cufon rendering a white space that doesn't seem to exist as cufon text - any thoughts on why that would happen also appreciated.

The solution turned out to be to render cufon on #main-menu-nav a rather than #main-menu-nav...

Comment: This question already has answers, but if you want to solve problems like this one on your own, take a look at [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: @jdigital - I do use firebug but I've been working on this site since 8:30am and beginning to melt round the edges. I was looking for a problem in the css...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a `cufon` in the way.

```
<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 4px; height: 20px; "><canvas width="14" height="22" style="width: 14px; height: 22px; top: -2px; left: 0px; "></canvas><cufontext> </cufontext></cufon>
```

Comment: It is! Thanks - now I just have to figure out what whitespace is being cufoned when it shouldn't!

Answer (score 0):

the issue is padding, specifically in `#menu-main-nav li a` The padding-top value needs to be 0.